# What function calls does Amazon FreeTime limit?

Tags: android, kindle-fire

I'm considering building an app for the Amazon Kindle Fire to be used under the FreeTime system. I don't have any knowledge of Java (yet) but I have a background in other programming languages. I haven't been able to find a list of functions that are restricted or blocked, except for a few mentions of WebView being disabled which has already thrown one of my implementation ideas out the window.

I tried asking this question on the Amazon Developer Forums, but was just given a link to the marketing for FreeTime, which isn't the kind of information I need. I have a Kindle Fire with FreeTime installed on it if that helps. Does anyone know? Is there a list somewhere of functions I can't use?